# What's wrong with my regex in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

```
m/(?<word>\w*a$)/
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Sequence (?<w...) not recognized in regex;
```

Comment: Looks like a named capture for any word that ends in a 'a'.  I have not used perl though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `(?<xxx>` syntax requires perl 5.10 or above: http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5100delta.html#Named-Capture-Buffers